# Parsing Twitter Created At Date as UTC

Tags: c#, datetime, twitter, timezone, datetime-format

I realize there are many threads about parsing twitter dates, but I am having a peculiar issue, and haven't been able to find any threads specific to this.

I am retrieving this post: https://twitter.com/bodegamcallen/status/1033757489567805440

which has a created date of **8/26/2018 at 9:46 AM** Central Time.

The created date in the api is this: "Sun Aug 26 16:46:06 +0000 2018"

Which makes sense as 16:46pm (2:46pm) UTC is 9:46 AM Central (-500).

However, I'm parsing this using this code:

```
statusModel.DatePosted = DateTime.ParseExact(
    this.created_at, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

and instead of getting the desired UTC time shown above, I'm getting this: **8/26/2018 4:46:06 PM**

If I change the DateTimeStyle to None or AssumeLocal, I get this: **8/26/2018 11:46:06 AM**

Neither of which is correct!

I've tried different formats from other threads like:

- "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy"
- "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
- "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"
- "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss +ffff yyyy"

I also tried using DateTimeOffset.Parse and changing the culture to mine (en-us)

they all give me the same results.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the datetime to be the same UTC time as the date value I'm getting from the API?

Comment: What is wrong with the output you're getting (what do you *want* it to be)? The first one appears to be exactly the same as the api date.

Comment: holy cow you're right, the problem is that the Twitter date is NOT UTC, the correct time would be 14:46 not 16:46... I now see the problem, but how the heck am I supposed compensate for this, two hour offset seems totally random???

Answer (score 0):

Aha! It turns out that my twitter account settings were configured to be in Pacific Time, rather than Central Time, and that would account for the two hour difference.

I changed my time zone settings for my account as described here: https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/how-to-change-time-zone-settings

And after changing to Central Time, the API data is coming in correct!

hope this helps someone else. Time zones, amirite?

Comment: The data coming from the API should still be normalized to UTC if the string includes `+0000`.  It would be very weird for it to show pacific time without showing `-0700` or `-0800` (depending on DST).

Comment: I thought that was weird too, but it absolutely fixed it. In fact when I first changed it I missed the selection so it was still off by 1 hour. When I selected my correct timezone it finally started coming in correctly.

Comment: Hmmm...  I think you'll find that the local time zone of your computer is influencing the result.   Try also changing your code as in my answer and then see if it still matters what your Twitter setting is.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- `zzzz` is not a valid specifier.  Always check [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) if you're uncertain.
- `K` is the only time zone specifier that is appropriate for `DateTime` parsing.  The others (`z`, `zz`, and `zzz`) are for `DateTimeOffset` parsing.
- When there is *any* offset or time zone information in the input string (even if it's `+0000` or `Z`), `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.ParseExact` will assume by default that you want the output kind to be `DateTimeKind.Local` and that you want the value adjusted to local whatever it is in the input string.  Examine the output `.Kind` if you're not certain if it's working correctly.  If you want UTC instead, you should pass `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`.
- You don't need to pass `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`, because there is time zone information present in the input string.
- It's not invalid, but you don't need to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat`.  It's sufficient, and more common, to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Putting this all together, your code should be:

```
statusModel.DatePosted = DateTime.ParseExact(
    this.created_at, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

And of course, you'd save some hassle and confusion if you changed your `DatePosted` to be a `DateTimeOffset` type instead.  It's superior for this sort of scenario, and then you don't have to worry about `DateTimeKind` or `DateTimeStyles`.

Comment: thanks for the detailed info! I'm certain I tried this variation; this really does seem to be affected by the timezones, becuase I did not change the code when I changed the time zone, and it absolutely changed. perhaps it's a coincidence, temporary but in twitter, who knows, all I know is after changing the selection, it finally started working :/